# How is it possible that the outcome is: firstvalue is 10 secondvalue is 20

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue

  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;
           // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue<< '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

How is it possible that the outcome is:
firstvalue is 10
secondvalue is 20

shouldn't it be first value is 20 and second is 10 because the compiler reads from start to finish?

Comment: Why do you expect `firstvalue` to be 20? The only line that modifies it is `*p1 = 10;`

Comment: Remove the `#include` and `using namespace std;` and both `cout <<` lines and you can visualize the code at [visualize C code execution](http://shorturl.at/aXZ45).

Comment: C++ is an imperative language, there is no "order of reading code", no "solution evaluation", there is order of events occurring according to instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In these statements

```
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;
```

at first firstvalue is set to 10 and then secondvalue is set also to 10.

After this assignment

```
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
```

now the pointer p1 points to secondvalue and in this statement

```
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20
```

secondvalue is reassigned with 20.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how does the value of *p1 stay 10?

Comment: @MatejCicek The value *p1 is equal to 20 because now the pointer p1 after this statement p1 = p2; points to secondvalue.

Answer (score 1):

`*p1 = 10` means that the variable where `p1` is pointing to is equal to `10`, so `firstvalue = 10`.

`p1 = p2` means that `p1` will now be pointing to the same variable as `p2`, so to `secondvalue`.

So if `p1` is now pointing to `secondvalue`, `*p1 = 20` means that `secondvalue = 20`.

`*p2 = *p1` is just to throw you off, assigning to `secondvalue`, (where `p2` is pointing to) the value of `10` temporarily till it's replaced later in the code by `*p1 = 20`.